# Error: error converting ".git" to absolute: Access is denied

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to execute some Windows batch scripts to sync the repository. I have configured the local repository so that it contains my login-password, since I do not have access to the user under which the Jenkins node is running. The credentials were entered correctly.

before on local repo:

```
git config lfs.https://<username>:<password>@gitlab.<mycompany>.com/<user>/<repname>.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
git remote set-url origin https://<username>:<password>@gitlab.<mycompany>.com/<user>/<repname>.git
```

after:

```
git push
```

log

```
Error: error converting ".git" to absolute: Access is denied.
warning: current Git remote contains credentials
ref sandbox:: Access is denied.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.<mycompany>/<user>/<somerep>.git'}
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

Perhaps there are some ideas to check?